# How to load single image from Photos

Tags: ios, swift

I use an UIImagePicker to choose an image from the photos app and would like to store the url and later reuse the same image.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        let asset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset]
        let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL] as! URL
        ...
```

Why is asset nil?
referenceURL is deprecated but contains something like assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=95554EBE-DAB8-4A36-9BEA-00BAB0174777&ext=JPG

```
private func loadImage() -> UIImage? {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "? = %@", "?")

    let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

    var image: UIImage? = nil

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    manager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: 0), targetSize: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { img, err  in
      image = img
    }
    return image
}
```

What should the predicate look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHAsset is `nil` because you didn't obtain user authorization for Photo Library usage beforehand. Your lack of authorization means yes, you can present the picker, and yes, the user can choose a photo, and yes, you can receive the photo *image*, but you can't look into the Photo Library.

If you get permission beforehand, the PHAsset will be an actual PHAsset and you can use that to go back and get further info about the asset from the Photo Library. Use the asset's *identifier* if you want to store a persistent reference to it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phobject/1622400-localidentifier

Comment: And what if the image was deleted?

Comment: What if it is? The OP didn’t ask whether storing a reference was wise, but how to do it.

Comment: "would like to *store* the url and *later* reuse the same image".

Comment: Yup. And this is how, and explains the nil result.